# Unity preloading prefab memory issue (Android)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image: Memory profile]
I am currently working on a battle simulation game, I used a plugin to help me solve the performance issue when rendering a lot of the same model at the same time (e.g. 300 archer), but it doesn't help much when they are different models (e.g. archer + rider + knight + 50 other types of soldiers).
Even if I didn't instantiate the model into the scene, by just keep the reference in one of the model spawning scripts, Unity seems to preload all the models into the memory and crash some of the low end Android device.

Does anyone know any tip and tricks that can help solving this issue?

Comment: Are those prefabs in "Resources" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that direct reference to the prefab will cause such issue. Using Resources.load() / addressable (assets bundle) gives us more control on such memory issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).